# Pove that certain system of equations has a solution iff $a \equiv b \pmod d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> If $\gcd(m, n) = d$, prove that the system $$
> \begin{cases}
> x\equiv a \pmod m \\ 
> x\equiv b \pmod n \\ 
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> has a soution iff $a \equiv b \pmod d$.

I'll go $\leftarrow$ just to see if I am going in the right direction:

$mu + nv = 1$ implies

$mu \equiv 0 \pmod m$,

$nv \equiv 1 \pmod m $,

$nv \equiv 0 \pmod n$,

$mu \equiv 1 \pmod n$

$b - a = dk$ and $mu + nv = d \rightarrow muk + nvk = b - a$. Then,

$t = muk + nvk = k \pmod m$

$t = muk + nvk = k \pmod n$

Does this $t$ make sense?

Comment: How do you solve $mu+nv=1$ when $\gcd(m,n)=d>1$?

Comment: I applied Chinese Remainder Theorem where $m, n$ are always(?) relatively prime.

Comment: They aren't relatively prime in this problem, so you can't do that.